# Dokku - Add domain after setup

Tags: node.js, dns, dokku

I installed Dokku on my Digital Ocean droplet, but did it before setting my dns records, so Dokku was installed on IP. Now I changed my dns record, so site can be accessed through `site.com`. I can access my previously created Dokku containers through `site.com:port`, how can I change Dokku settings to access my app like this - `appname.site.com`

Comment: Try to explore this file: `/home/dokku/VHOST`.

Comment: Sure could use a way to reset the initial Dokku configuration to gain access to the setup GUI. Since I left domain configuration IP based, there is no VHOST file and I have no idea what it is supposed to contain.

Comment: The `/home/dokku/VHOST` file contains the "top-level" domain for your server. For instance, if you want an app name like `app.dokku.me`, your file would contain `dokku.me`.

Answer (score 19):

Per https://github.com/progrium/dokku:

> Set up a domain and a wildcard domain pointing to that host. Make sure
>   /home/dokku/VHOST is set to this domain. By default it's set to
>   whatever hostname the host has. This file is only created if the
>   hostname can be resolved by dig (dig +short $(hostname -f)). Otherwise
>   you have to create the file manually and set it to your preferred
>   domain. If this file still is not present when you push your app,
>   dokku will publish the app with a port number (i.e.
>   http://example.com:49154 - note the missing subdomain).

To fix the issue, you will first need to update the /home/dokku/VHOST file, adding the domain name -- this will fix any newly generated deployments, but existing apps will need to be deleted from the /home/dokku directory by name (/home/dokku/foo, /home/dokku/bar, etc.) and redeployed for this change to take effect, since each Dokku application has a separate nginx.conf within those /home/dokku/ paths and those will need to be re-written.

Comment: Just a note for anyone else, you may need to re-link containers (for instance if you are using a db plugin) if you delete and then add an app.Editing the /home/dokku/foo/nginx.conf properly would save that step

Comment: Deleting the apps may be overkill, try `dokku ps:restart <app>` or `dokku ps:rebuild <app>` first.

Answer (score 8):

It is indeed not necessary to destroy and recreate apps. First, `dokku domains:report` tells you if global VHOSTS are already enabled or not. If not, run

```
dokku domains:add-global yourdomain.tld
echo yourdomain.tld | sudo tee -a /home/dokku/VHOST
dokku domains:add myapp myapp.yourdomain.tld
dokku domains:enable myapp
```

The first of these adds yourdomain.tld to /home/dokku/HOSTNAME. It should also add it to /home/dokku/VHOST, but it doesn't. So that needs to be done manually. Then tell dokku what (sub)domain you want to access myapp on. The last command sets the NO_VHOST variable for myapp to false.

Answer (score 5):

To extend [@shirkey answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317907/1560827): you don't need to re-create (destroy and create again) an app in order to apply those changes. You can manually create VHOST file inside `/home/dokku/$APP/` directory (as dokku user) then remove NO_VHOST setting (`dokku config:unset $app NO_VHOST`) and change `DOKKU_NGINX_PORT` to 80 (`dokku config:set $app DOKKU_NGINX_PORT=80`) and restart the app (`dokku ps:restart $app`).

Answer (score 3):

$ echo "example.com" > /home/dokku/VHOST

Answer (score 0):

If you still could add a subdomain. These are the points to check.

**Example: add `myapp.example.com`.**

**1, DNS(e.g. Namecheap)**

If you are using Cloudflare, Check if Custom DNS is set to Cloudflare.

**2, CDN(e.g. Cloudflare)**

Check if it has A record like this.

```
Type  |  Name   |   Content 
A     |  myapp  |  public ip address of Digital ocean server
```

**3, VPS(e.g. Digital Ocean)**

If you use Cloudflare you don’t have to set up Domain setting on Digital Ocean.

**4, Dokku**

- Is port mapping set up properly? `dokku proxy:report` to check port 80
  is mapped to the port of container.
- Is the server running? Use `curl`    from inside the server.

If you still could not locate the cause of the problem, check nginx config file like `/home/dokku/appname/nginx.conf` `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  manually.

Example `/home/dokku/appname/nginx.conf` file

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name myapp.example.com; 

location    / {
  proxy_pass  http://myapp-3030;
}

upstream myapp-3030 {

  server 172.17.0.4:3030;
}
```